# listview row height

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to set listview row height without making custom listview and new arrayadapter. 
I am setting height to LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT; i get this in logcat

```
02-19 20:42:25.721: E/AndroidRuntime(6936): at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2465) 02-19 20:42:25.721: 
                    E/AndroidRuntime(6936): at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1250)
```

Here is my View code :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                 System.gc();
                 TextView tv = new TextView(mContext.getApplicationContext());
                 LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                 LayoutParams params = tv.getLayoutParams();
                 String id = null;
              mRowHeight = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                 if (params == null) {
                       music_column_index = musiccursor
.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
                       musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
                       id = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
                       music_column_index = musiccursor
.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE);
                       musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
                       id += musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
                       tv.setText(id);
                       params.height = mRowHeight;
                 } else
                       tv = (TextView) convertView;
                 return tv;
```

Comment: is there any specific reason you are calling `System.gc()` in getView which is a function called quite often?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> E/AndroidRuntime(6936): at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2465) 02-19
>   20:42:25.721: E/AndroidRuntime(6936): at
>   android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1250)

Your error means that `getView()` method will return **`null`** in some case(s).
I'm little confused from your code, you nowhere inflating `convertView` if is null.

Your approach is too messy and not correct. I suggest you to create `XML` layout for row, then inflate `convertView` with this layout and then set appropriate widgets(textViews) with data from `Cursor`.

```
if (convertView == null) {
   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.someRowLayout, null, false);
   // if you have RowHolder so set him as tag to convertView
}
else {
      // just recycle it if you have holder
}
if (cursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
   String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.COLUMN_NAME));
   if (data != null && data.length() > 0) {
      TextView t = findViewById(R.id.someId);
      t.setText(data);
   }
}
```

Comment: In this case you can use either `convertView = new TextView(context);` or `convertView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);` since you don't want to use an extra layout.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am going to try this now..i didnt like the method of making row xml, cause this listview loads lots of stuf from phone..

Comment: textview has to be in row xml? or i just can do TextView tv = new TextView(mContext.getApplicationContext());